# Programatically modifying a HTML page from ASP.NET

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web app with a standard default.aspx, from within which I need to load a html page from another site (all internal intranet) and pre-populate form input controls on that loaded html page using ASP variables. Specifically, username / pwd on a login form based user details loaded by the aspx from a db. The html page also contains a considerable amount of js (shouldn't directly impact this question though).

Not sure of the best route to approach this. I have considered:
1. Loading the html page in a frame, then somehow manipulating it's DOM from another frame loaded from the aspx.
2. Loading the html during aspx page load or render, then replacing the relevant sections of the html with the new values.

I have had a stab at both approaches and ran into issues. With (2) the resulting HTML isn't recognized as HTML by the browser at all (despite the written response being just the original html relayed from the original site). I can see the HTML source in the browser, but the page itself appears blank.

Answers warmly anticipated. Thank-you.

Answer (score 0):

1.if you want to go wityh iframe 
You can easily modify values from communicate between parent window and iframe

```
 from  parent to iframe function
  document.querySelector('iframe').contentWindow.ChildFunction(33);
 from  chhild to parentfunction
     parent.parentfunction("4rom child")
```

make a function in iframe that accept an object (from parent) and populate it in.
 make a function in parent that accept an object (from child) .

---

2.how are you "Loading the html during aspx page load or render,"
 - ajax or something else?
 -making a user controll
  both should work fine .
( could you tell how are you loading html ?)(as it should have worked)